# Clicked some option for 'localization' and now updates takes 5-10 minutes

Tags: notepad++, localization

I think I clicked some option for 'localization' in Notepad++. But I can't find that option now, to undo it. Currently, each time Notepad++ updates, it takes 5-10 minutes for all the local natural languages (e.g., German, Serbian, etc.) to get updated. I only need English.

I would appreciate any suggestions for how to get rid of the need for Notepad++ to spend time installing or updating other natural languages, when Notepad++ updates.

I don't use any natural languages other than English, French and Hebrew.

Comment: Go to `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\localization` (or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\localization`) and delete the language files that you don't need. See if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have checked the `Localization` checkbox when installing Notepad++. You can run Notepad++ installer again and make sure that you do not check this box. That should set your Notepad++ installation with English, without many languages to pick from and the updates should be also faster.

(p.s. Just in case, if it does not work, uninstall NPP first and then reinstall it.)

[image: notepad++ language localizations]